# Minimum cost to reach destination using a train - RStudio errors

Tags: r

I tried to "translate" working code from Python to R as best as I could, but I get erro, that i am not sure how to deal with. `Error: C stack usage  7971064 is too close to the limit`. Can you please help me out? Thank you.

This is the code

```
N<-4
intMax<-2147483647

data1 <- c(0, 15, 80, 90, 
    intMax, 0, 40, 50, 
    intMax, intMax,0, 70, 
    intMax, intMax, intMax, 0)
cost <- matrix(data1, nrow = 4, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)

minCostRec <- function(cost, s, d){
if(s == d||s+1 == d){
    return cost[s][d]
}
minimal <- cost[s][d]
i<-s+1
for(i in i<d){
    c <- minCostRec(cost, s, i) + minCostRec(cost, i, d)
    if(c < minimal){
        minimal <- c
    }
}
return minimal
}

minCost <- function(cost){
return minCostRec(cost, 0, N-1)
}

print(paste("minimum cost to reach station", N, "is",minCost(cost)))
```

Comment: This should be `return(cost[s][d])` , `return(minimal)` and `return(minCostRec(cost, 0, N-1))` or just don't use `return` all together

Comment: Thank you, i corrected it. Now error is only this: Error: C stack usage  7971064 is too close to the limit

Comment: So did you google this error?

Comment: yes I did, but it is usually related to recursive functions and things like that, but it is different each time depenmding on the code.

Comment: 1. You have some syntax errors in your coed. The correct syntax for return is return(variable) and not return variable and for tables we do table[1,2] and not table[1][2]. After you fix those the error become "node stack Overflow" and I believe the reason for that is because you call the function minCostRec   inside the function minCostRec

Comment: Thank you, tables are corrected, I still get an Error: C stack usage  7971064 is too close to the limit. Yes I call minCostRect in itself, but that is a point of recursive function. Also, it work in C++ and Python, so question is, how can I make it work in R?